# Is there any way to get the information in XML, or GeoJSON or in any text format for this ArcGIS from URL?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-10.0, wms, png

I have a URL like this

> https://arcgisserver.lund.se/arcgis/rest/directories/arcgisoutput/extern/Extern_Stadsplanering_MapServer/_ags_mapd3b02fb986704186a28a270abd0baff1.png

Source Page

> https://geoportal.lund.se/portal/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=b49e2d6859dd4b2c9d9ae523f1d92cd9

Is there a way to generate the XML or JSON file from this so that I can get the polygon coordinates from the server? For example in WMS we can change the format to KML and we will get the XML file with coordinates. Is there is a method in ArcGIS or is it impossible to get that data from this URL?

Comment: You need to go to the endpoint to get information (JPEG won't cut it).

Comment: As Vince mentioned, the first URL is to an exported map image that won't do you any good for extracted coordinates of objects in the image.  It appears the host has disabled the [Services Directory](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/using-the-services-directory.htm), so you will have to query the [Map Service](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/map-service.htm) ArcGIS REST API directly generating your own queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify the source of the layer that's been used and published, after checking the site, i identified the source of that layer (this maybe incorrect source), and then from that layer, generated this url, you can call this URL and it will return the geojson of all the polygons that's available on that service, Furthermore you can change the params for the request.

```
https://geoportal.lund.se/arcgis/rest/services/GenerellaTjanster/Lund_Search/MapServer/12/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&timeRelation=esriTimeRelationOverlaps&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnExtentOnly=false&sqlFormat=none&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&f=geojson
```

Comment: looks like you found the arcgis service directory link, seems like i overlooked it: https://geoportal.lund.se/arcgis/rest/

Answer (score 0):

The layer seems to have been published as dynamic layer which serves the layer as - on demand basis. If it were a normal feature layer, then we would be able to load it in arcmap. there is a workaround solution but it is going to be tedious and you will only be able to access and extract single feature by clicking each polygon. first open the link and then open developer console on chrome. then go to network tab and then click on the layer:

[image]

open the highlighted query in new tab which will display the geojson file with geometry

[image]

save it as query.json on your drive and then open arcmap. search for the tool json to feature and convert the file to shapefile. this way you will be able to extract the geometry of the polygon.

[image]

Comment: As u mentioned it is going to be tedious. I want  the geometry at once for all polygons